# Get matplotlib automatic y tick values in a list

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

Edit:
I tried the following.

```
auto_y_ticks=list(axes2.get_yticklabels())
```

But still the output is not a list of tick values. It shows as Matplotlib text.

The following code produces bar and line plot in the same graph.
In the secondary y axis, the ytick values range from -1 to +1. 
My question is, how do I store these values in a list?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()          
N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)    
ind = np.arange(N)
plt.ylim(0.0, 65.0)
plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd, label='Men means')
plt.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd, label='Women means')
plt.ylabel('Bar plot')      

x = np.linspace(0, N)
y = np.sin(x)
axes2 = plt.twinx()
axes2.plot(x, y, color='k', label='Sine')
axes2.set_ylim(-1, 1)
axes2.set_ylabel('Line plot')

plt.show()
```

auto_y_ticks=list(What's the logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code,

```
axes2.get_yticks()
```

gives

```
array([-1.  , -0.75, -0.5 , -0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ])
```

Which is what you're after, right?

Comment: Yes! Instead of looking at axes2.get_yticks(), I was looking at axes2.get_yticklabels()

Comment: Great. Personally, I wish it were called `axes2.get_ytick_values()`.  `yticks` sounds like objects to me, but there's probably something I don't understand in the naming choice.